# ResolveClientUrl when page path ends with backslash

Tags: asp.net

I noticed that Page.ResolveClientUrl resolves to an incorrect path when URL of the Page it is used on ends with a backslash. For example:

```
http://localhost/Default.aspx
-> Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/style.css") returns "Styles/style.css" (correct)

http://localhost/Default.aspx\
-> Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/style.css") returns "../Styles/style.css" (incorrect)
```

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent an incorrect path from being returned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResolveUrl`. 
`ResolveClientUrl` returns a path relative to the current page, and `ResolveUrl` returns a path relative to the site root.

```
Page.ResolveUrl("~/layout/images/andornotLogo.gif")

"/layout/images/andornotLogo.gif"

Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/layout/images/andornotLogo.gif")

"../layout/images/andornotLogo.gif"
```

Comment: I know about ResolveUrl, but I'm still curious why ResolveClientUrl behaves this way? As it stands, it is unusable if I can't rely on its results.

Comment: In second case, It treats Default.aspx as folder. So, It returns ../ in the result